# Can i send an entire JSON object using post method in AFNetworking

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, afnetworking, afnetworking-2

Is it possible to send a JSON object to web service (RESTful) using AFNetworking AFHTTPRequestOperationManager method post ? I know we can send key value pairs though dictionary and that can be serialized as a JSON through POST request but this about more complex object as follows

```
{
  "User":{ "name":"blah", "id":"blah blah" }
  "department":"something" 
}
```

The code i was trying was this

```
 NewUser *user = [NewUser sharedNewUser];

     NSDictionary *params = @ {@"FirstName" :user.strFname, @"LastName" :user.strLname,@"Email":user.strEmail,@"PhoneNumber":user.strNum,@"Password":user.strPwd,@"Token":@""};

    NSMutableDictionary *jsonDic = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    [jsonDic setValue:params forKey:@"Client"];

    AFHTTPClient *client = [[AFHTTPClient alloc] initWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"URL"]];


    [client postPath:@"chauffr_services/servicestack/RegisterClient?format=json" parameters:jsonDic
             success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
                 NSLog(@"%@",responseObject);
                 NSDictionary *json = responseObject;


             } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {

             }];
```

Comment: If you can send a dictionary as json in AFNetworking, then you should be able to send this object too, in the same way. Whats the problem?

Comment: Your parameter dictionary will be something like `NSDictionary *param = @{ @"User" : @{@"name" : @"blah", @"id" : @"blah blah"}, @"department" : @"something" };`

Comment: Did you tried before asking ?

Comment: @DavidAnsermot you really think i will do like that ?

Comment: @Akhilrajtr thanks but question is will post method accept or accepts  that kind of complex object as it was not working in my case

Comment: @vishal I'm with `David Ansermot` here if you have tried it then you will have gotten your answer and you should be doing some sort of research before asking the question and doing it yourself will have been the perfect place to start.

Comment: you simply need to set your POST request body as your complex object's data. As long as it's valid JSON, there won't be any issue.

Comment: dear @DavidAnsermot i tried and it wasn't posting data to service, hence was the question finally i got solved it , and remember not every person asking question here is lazy , you can ignore question if you feel so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was trying to send object to service but the jSON wasn't reaching the RESTful service , what i was missing is following line

```
[httpclient setParameterEncoding:AFJSONParameterEncoding];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using this custom method:

```
- (NSString *)jsonStringFromID:(id)object {
NSError *error;
NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:object options:(NSJSONWritingOptions)(0) error:&error];

if (!jsonData) {
    NSLog(@"Json Print: error: %@", error.localizedDescription);
    return @"{}";
}
else {
    return [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
}
```

}

Call this method by passing your json object to it.
Enjoy!!!

Edited:
Try to add request serializer as json type. Maybe it works for you..

```
[[AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager] setRequestSerializer:[AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer]];
[[[AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager] requestSerializer] setValue:@"application/json; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
```

Comment: problem is when i use it with post method as i said in original question its not working , i tried what you are suggesting

Comment: I have updated the answer. Please check if it resolves your issue.. :)